# Win8.1 Pro + VS2013 : Selecting the right project types for my Windows solution?

Tags: c, windows, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have developed a C/C++ library which compiles across
different platforms and targets.

On each platform and for each target for that platform, 
I would like to develop a UI which interfaces with the library. For example,
pressing a button in the UI results in a call to some 
function in my C/C++ static library.

On Windows I would like to target the following:

- Windows 7
- Windows 8
- Windows Tablets
- Windows Phone 8.1

For each of those targets I would like the UI to look
more or less the same - and optimally (if possible) 
be able to use the same UI project (literally the same code) 
for all targets.

The question is IF this is possible?
And if it's possible, which project types should
I select when I create the VS2013 solution? There are so
many different project types to choose from.

As I see it, the solution would consist of 3 projects:

- UI project
- C/C++ static library
- IF NEEDED: A project which acts as "glue" between the UI project
  and the static library

If it's not possible to use the same UI project for all targets,
then my question would be what type of UI project do I select
for the individual targets? I assume that the project type for
my C/C++ static library remains the same across targets.

For desktop targets I would prefer that the UI is contained within
the traditional, typical program window which can either be in the
foreground (visible), background (minimized as an icon on task bar)
or closed (exit).

I'm not too crazy about those new Win8 apps which take up the entire screen 
(I believe those type of apps are called 'store apps'?).

I am on Windows 8.1 Pro.

I'm hoping that I can get some good advice before I start out with this project.